# How to get values of input types by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

This is how i have written my values.

```
<input type='text' class='textVerdana11' style='text-align:right' id='test1' name='test[]' value='1' />
<input type='text' class='textVerdana11' style='text-align:right' id='test2' name='test[]' value='2' />
<input type='text' class='textVerdana11' style='text-align:right' id='test3' name='test[]' value='3' />
```

Now the problem at hand is that i have to extract the values by name because the `id`s can be anything in jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: How about `$('[name=\'test[]\']')` ?

Answer (score 4):

[Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) can be used to select elements, then [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)  to create an array of values.

```
 var array = $('[name="test[]"]').map(function() {
   return $(this).val();
 }).get();
```

Comment: The solution from mic4ael will work, but map is much more efficient (I learnt this the hard way) @HirenMaster

Answer (score 1):

I think, something like this should work

```
$('[name="test[]"]').each(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this :

```
$(function(){
var values = $("input[name='test\\[\\]']")
              .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();

alert(values);
});
```